# Ask of ReaderT is not deducing the Monad type correctly

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, purescript

I'm trying to write code with ReaderT in purescript. But my compiler isn't deducting the type correctly

```
type Doc' = ReaderT Level (Writer (Array String)) String

line' :: String -> Doc' 
line' input = do 
       space <-  ask  -- error line
       lift $ tell $ [(power " " space) <> input <> "\n"]
```

The error thrown is

```
Could not match type
        
    Unit
        
  with type

    String

  while trying to match type t0 t1
     with type ReaderT @Type Int (WriterT (Array String) Identity) String
  while checking that expression (bind ask) (\space ->
                                             (apply lift) ((...) [ ...
                                                                 ]
                                                          )
                                          )
  has type ReaderT @Type Int (WriterT (Array String) Identity) String
  in value declaration line'

  where t0 is an unknown type
        t1 is an unknown type
```

> Why the ask can't deduct the type automatically... I'm very new to FP,
> am I doing something fundamentally wrong?
> Why its saying cant match type of Unit with String. I'm not using Unit anywhere

Comment: `tell` retuns a unit, so the type should be `ReaderT Level (Writer (Array String)) ()` of `Doc'`.

Comment: I think `Doc'` is just a bad type synonym. The main ways one interacts with `ReaderT` are via functions that will happily change its last type argument but leave the other two the same. As such, it's really hostile to create a type synonym that fixes all three. You can't use that particular synonym the way you'd really want to. It should be replaced with one that doesn't fix the third parameter.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this does not work is because `tell` has type [**`tell :: (MonadTell w m, Monad m) => w -> m Unit`**](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-transformers/4.2.0/docs/Control.Monad.Writer.Class#v:tell). You use [**`lift :: (MonadTrans t, Monad m) => m a -> t m a`**](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-transformers/4.2.0/docs/Control.Monad.Trans.Class#v:lift), but this will not "return type" `a`, so the type of your `line'` is:

```
--                                           Unit 🖟  🖟
type Doc' = ReaderT Level (Writer (Array String)) Unit

line' :: String -> Doc' 
line' input = do 
       space <- ask
       lift $ tell $ [(power " " space) <> input <> "\n"]
```